# trying to install chef-client package via local yum repo

Tags: yum, rpm, gpg, chef

I am trying to make chef-11.16.4-1.el6.x86_64.rpm available to our servers via a local yum repo that we've built.

it is not available in RHEL Repos, so i had to manually download and save it in our repo.

so here is what i did on yum repo server:

```
1. cd /packages/rhel65-base/; wget https://opscode-omnibus-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/el/6/x86_64/chef-11.16.4-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
2. createrepo /packages/rhel65-base/
```

Yum client was able to see the new package available:

```
[user1@testserver01 ~]$ yum list chef
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, security
Installed Packages
chef.x86_64            11.16.0-1.el6                   installed
Available Packages
chef.x86_64            11.16.4-1.el6                   local-rhel65-base
```

But when trying to install the latest package of chef, it ends with below error:

```
warning: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 83ef826a: NOKEY

Public key for chef-11.16.4-1.el6.x86_64.rpm is not installed
```

Assuming that the chef rpm has not been signed, i tried to sign it myself by following https://iuscommunity.org/pages/CreatingAGPGKeyandSigningRPMs.html but still couldn't get it working.

Some useful info i can find in Chef's website is the SHA1 checksum value of this package.

Anyone got ideas/suggestions to solve this issue? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the package isn't signed, the simplest solution is probably `yum --nogpgcheck install chef`.  If you have a local repository, you can set:

```
gpgcheck=no
```

In the corresponding `.repo` file.

Comment: yes, it works with nogpgcheck option, but i am looking for help with installing the rpm with gpg enabled. thanks

Comment: That wasn't clear from your question. Can you update your question with details of the steps you went through to (a) sign the package and (b) import the signing key on your systems?  And include any errors you get, or places where the behavior you see is different from the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you haven't configured your server to accept the key that signed the package as a valid GPG key for this repo.

The easiest solution is of course to run yum with `nogpgcheck`, though it's obviously also less secure. But if you've downloaded the package and verified it, and are keeping it in a place where it shouldn't be possible to tamper with it, it may be acceptable.

If this isn't acceptable, you need to fetch the public part of the key that was used to sign the package and place it on the server where you're trying to install the package. You should be able to do it by simply copying the key there and running `rpm -i /path/to/RPM-GPG-KEY-REPONAME`.

The key should normally be placed in `/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-REPONAME`. Also check the repo file for your repo in `/etc/yum.repos.d` so that it contains the following lines:

```
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-REPONAME
gpgcheck=1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but still valuable to answer I believe to prevent misleading information. The package is signed as you can see from the message :

```
Public key for chef-11.16.4-1.el6.x86_64.rpm is not installed
```

However the key isn't installed... I tried to search for this package key but couldn't find an url for it (This is what led me here in fact). When found/validated you can import it via:

```
rpm --import <url>
```

The solution from @larsks *disabled* the checking of the gpg key...